# How to Display Individual Tables in Dropdowns from SQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have 5 dropdowns on a tab of a website. I have a database table in MS SQL Server. The table has all the data of 5 dropdowns with one of the fieldNames called Region_Name, say the Region_Names are A, B, C, D, and E. I have written codes to display a table and enabled row editing for one of the RegionNames. Now, I am wondering if I could modify the same codes to display associated table with row editing enabled using different queries when a dropdown is clicked. That could reduce the code repetition and improve the performance. But I do not know how to achieve this. Could anyone please give me some hints? I am using PHP PDO to connect to the database.

My codes to display the table is shown below. I am using Datatables plugin and tableExport Jquery plug in. For simplicity, I have not copied the links and libraries for plugins. I can show my edit.php if that will be helpful.

```
<?php

 require_once('include/database.php');
 ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

<title>Matrix</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
 <body>


<header>


</header> <br/>

<div id="container">

<table id="myTable" class="display" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px"      
 width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 1px">ID</th>
        <th style="width: 1px">Site</th>
        <th style="width: 1px">Location</th>

        <th style="width: 1px">Remarks</th>

        <th width="1px">Action</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
    <?php
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM MATRIX WHERE    
    Region_Name='Charlotte'");
    $stmt ->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?=$row['ID'];?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Site']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Location']; ?></td>

            <td><?= $row['Remarks']; ?></td>

            <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?= $row['ID']; ?>"> Edit</a></td>


        </tr>


        <?php
    }
    ?>

    </tbody>

</table>

<br/>


 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your code? What have you achieved?

Comment: *Could anyone please give me some hints?*  Show your code...

Comment: I just added my simplified version of the codes to display the individual table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '<your database name>'` to get all the table in your database.

You can also get all the columns of table with this query

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='<your table name>'
```